# How do I make a select based on a function with Like?

Tags: mysql, sql

From another thread I got this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ShowWhiteSpace (@str varchar(8000))
RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ShowWhiteSpace varchar(8000);
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = @str
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(32), '[?]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(13), '[CR]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(10), '[LF]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(9),  '[TAB]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(1),  '[SOH]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(2),  '[STX]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(3),  '[ETX]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(4),  '[EOT]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(5),  '[ENQ]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(6),  '[ACK]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(7),  '[BEL]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(8),  '[BS]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(11), '[VT]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(12), '[FF]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(14), '[SO]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(15), '[SI]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(16), '[DLE]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(17), '[DC1]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(18), '[DC2]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(19), '[DC3]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(20), '[DC4]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(21), '[NAK]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(22), '[SYN]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(23), '[ETB]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(24), '[CAN]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(25), '[EM]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(26), '[SUB]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(27), '[ESC]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(28), '[FS]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(29), '[GS]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(30), '[RS]')
    SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(31), '[US]')
    RETURN(@ShowWhiteSpace)
END


select DBO.SHOWWHITESPACE(ITEM_NUM) FROM ITEM
```

And I with this I get a list with some lines with [CR][LF] at the end of them. So I would love to select only those so I can replace them all at the same time. How do I do this?

My idea was to do something like this... but it returns nothing. And I know that it should return 4 lines.

```
select DBO.SHOWWHITESPACE(i.ITEM_NUM) as ITEN_NUM 
FROM ITEM i
WHERE i.ITEM_NUM LIKE '%CR%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the function in the `WHERE` clause too, to get only those rows which contain `CR`:

```
select DBO.SHOWWHITESPACE(i.ITEM_NUM) as ITEN_NUM 
FROM ITEM i
WHERE DBO.SHOWWHITESPACE(i.ITEM_NUM) LIKE '%CR%'
```

**EDIT:**

I'm under the impression that, as per what you said in the comments, you are looking for a `UPDATE` to modify the contents of the column with the result of the function. If that is the case, what you need is the following query:

```
UPDATE ITEM
SET ITEM_NUM = DBO.SHOWWHITESPACE(ITEM_NUM)
```

This will update **all** of your rows, so in case you want to update only those 4 rows which contain `CR`, then you need to add a `WHERE` clause, thus transforming your query into:

```
UPDATE ITEM
SET ITEM_NUM = DBO.SHOWWHITESPACE(ITEM_NUM)
WHERE DBO.SHOWWHITESPACE(ITEM_NUM) LIKE '%CR%'
```

Comment: Followup question... How would I update those rows in the real database?   SELECT ITEM_NUM
FROM ITEM r
WHERE r.ITEM_NUM 
IN (select DBO.SHOWWHITESPACE(i.ITEM_NUM) as ITEM_NUM 
FROM ITEM i
WHERE DBO.SHOWWHITESPACE(i.ITEM_NUM) LIKE '%CR%') --> this will just return nothing currently. ITEM_NUM is the key.

Comment: @DanAndersson Well, of course this doesn't return anything, because your original `r.ITEM_NUM` is different than the result you get from `DBO.SHOWWITESPACE(i.ITEM_NUM)`, because you replaced characters in the function and the two are different.

Comment: Yeah I figured that much and realized it wouldn't work this way and made a manual change on the 4 lines. But in the future I'd like to know how to do it via code :)

Comment: @DanAndersson Code? You mean with a different language than SQL?

Comment: Thank you. I'd assume I could use the same to delete those 4 rows by just switching out UPDATE to DELETE.